# Change the delimiter in saveAsTextFile Option in Pyspark rdd

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have my dataset available in HDFS. I am reading it and performing filter operation.

```
dir = sc.textFile('/datasets/DelayedFlights.csv').filter(lambda x: 
int(x.split(',')[24]) == 1).map(lambda y: y.split(','))
The output of above operation is
[u'1763', u'2008', u'1', u'3', u'4', u'922.0', u'915', u'', u'1050', u'WN', 
u'1069', u'N630WN', u'', u'95.0', u'', u'', u'7.0', u'SAN', u'SMF', u'480', 
u'', u'12.0', u'0', u'N', u'1', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']
[u'1911', u'2008', u'1', u'3', u'4', u'2325.0', u'1900', u'', u'2030', 
u'WN', u'2092', u'N302SW', u'', u'90.0', u'', u'', u'265.0', u'SFO', u'SAN', 
u'447', u'', u'11.0', u'0', u'N', u'1', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']
[u'2651', u'2008', u'1', u'4', u'5', u'1949.0', u'1905', u'', u'1910', 
u'WN', u'1403', u'N504SW', u'', u'65.0', u'', u'', u'44.0', u'BOI', u'RNO', 
u'335', u'', u'11.0', u'0', u'N', u'1', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']
```

I want to change save the above file to HDFS path using saveAsTextFile with tab delimiter
Can any one say me how to change delimiter from comma to tab in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this to convert the RDD to a dataframe and save the dataframe with format csv with delimiter option set to tab as shown below.

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([['1763', '2008', '1', '3', '4', '922.0'], ['1763', '2008', '1', '3', '4', '922.0'], ['1763', '2008', '1', '3', '4', '922.0']])
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd.map(lambda x: tuple(x)))
df.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').option("delimiter", '\t').save('/path/to/csv/file/')
```

If you dont want to convert your rdd to dataframe the follow the below snippet.

```
rdd.map(lambda x: '\t'.join(x)).saveAsTextFile('test_dir/output')
```

The DataFrame approach is recommended over the above approach.

Comment: can you tell me why you have used tuple(x) for creating dataframe rather than createDataFrame(rdd,schema)

Comment: that is because each element of the tuple will be considered as separate column. for eg  `[('a1', 'b1', 'c1'), ('a2', 'b2', 'c2'), ('a3', 'b3', 'c3')]` this will create an DataFrame of 3 columns..

Comment: I am getting this error TypeError: 'DataFrameWriter' object is not callable

Comment: what is the version of your SPARK?

Comment: i am using spark 1.6.1

Comment: make sure you include this package (https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) or upgrade to spark 2.x

Comment: @hadooppractise why do you use Spark 1.6.1?

Comment: @AKSW My HDP instance comes with  spark 1.6.1